# Visual Studio Code - push branch to origin

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have a little issue with the latest Visual Studio Code Version. (1.40.0)

The issue is when I try to push a new local branch to the repository with the Visual Studio GUI. 
There is a little Icon with a "push" symbol in the bottom left corner. (See screenshot 1) Previously when I clicked it, it pushed the local branch to the only available remote (See screenshot 2)

Now it constantly asks me where to push it. And I have to manually click the only available origin... This is quite annoying because I'm constantly forgetting to make this new additional click.

Then later in the Online Repository I am always wondering: "*WHERE IS MY BRANCH?! Oh right... I forgot to make this new additional useless click again...*"

So how can I restore the previous behavior, that it automatically selects the ONLY available remote?
I just want it to execute `git push --set-upstream origin localbranchname`

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in Visual Studio Code. It is fixed by now and should be in the next version.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/85505

> Already fixed in master. Uff. This angered a lot of people. Easy.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to execute your command manually, i.e.:

```
git push --set-upstream origin localbranchname
```

and type it into git bash in your git repository?

From what I can see here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_git-status-bar-actions

It says that if you have set upstream for your branch, it will show the synchronization icon. In you case, it shows the publish icon instead.

Comment: I can type in `git push --set-upstream origin localbranchname`. If I do this it is working like before. The icon in Visual Studio Code then changes to the "synchronize" Icon. (like before) However the first click (With the publish icon) used to work with one click. Now it's 2 clicks.

Comment: There is a git setting for what to do with `git push` when you don't write where to push it. The setting is called `push.default`, and you can try it like this on a new branch: `git -c push.default=current push`. Maybe you can use one of these options for git, and Visual Studio Code will work as you want. You can find all options for `git.push` here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pushdefault

Comment: Thank you. I tried changing push.default, but said extra click is still necessary in VS-Code. I found the solution here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/85505  It was a bug that is fixed now